# Unable to Execute Plan command and terraform provider file is being not created in PC after terraform init

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I'm using terraform version v0.12.14. whenever I use terraform init I'm unable to see the terraform provider in my folder(hidden files are enabled to visible). also the plan command always fails with the error " no changes, infrastructure is up-to-date". kindly help me since I'm getting these errors I am not able to create the resource group in azure.

Comment: Please do not post screenshots. Code blocks are much more useful as they can be used to reproduce the issue. No changes message does not mean the plan failed, rather that there are not any changes between the code and what is in terraform state file.

Comment: Hello Marko, thanks for your reply. successfully deleted the screenshot. but actually i'am not able to create resource group

Comment: Ok, but you still haven't posted any code that leads to that issue.